# How to order results from CouchbaseViewQuery on Couchbase PHP SDK 2.0?

Tags: php, couchbase, couchbase-view

I started studying both Couchbase and MongoDB to decide wich one to implement on a social network, but the lack of documentation on couchbase side is almost making me give up.

Almost everything I must guess, as documentation are poor, and easier to get confuse between PHP SDK 2.0 and previous versions. There is a lot of documentation but about older sdk versions.

http://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-php-client-2.0.2/index.html

**Now after my outflow, my question.**

I have this code, and the necessary view created:

```
$cb = CouchbaseViewQuery::from('dev_testimonials', 'by_uid')->key($uid)->limit($max)->skip($inicio);
```

It works as expected, except that I need to order the results by ascending or descending, but I could't find anywhere documentation about that. I thought ->descending(true)  should do the trick but doesn't work. Doesn't exist.

All that the API reference says about ordering on CouchbaseViewQuery, is a list of constants:

**UPDATE_BEFORE, UPDATE_NONE, UPDATE_AFTER, ORDER_ASCENDING, ORDER_DESCENDING**

But there is not explanation about how and where to use them.

Could you help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you need to use is `order()` which accepts one of two constants:

- ORDER_ASCENDING
- ORDER_DESCENDING

In php all [class](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php#108944) constants are publicly visible. To access the constants the following code can be used: `CouchbaseViewQuery::ORDER_ASCENDING` or `CouchbaseViewQuery::ORDER_DESCENDING`.

Below is a code example using the [Beer-sample](http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/Misc/sample-bucket-intro.html) data shipped with Couchbase Server.

```
<?php
// Connect to Couchbase Server

$cluster = new CouchbaseCluster('http://127.0.0.1:8091');
$bucket = $cluster->openBucket('beer-sample');
$query = CouchbaseViewQuery::from('beer', 'by_location')->skip(6)->limit(2)->reduce(false)->order(CouchbaseViewQuery::ORDER_ASCENDING);
$results = $bucket->query($query);

foreach($results['rows'] as $row) {
        var_dump($row['key']);
}

echo "Reversing the order\n";

$query = CouchbaseViewQuery::from('beer', 'by_location')->skip(6)->limit(2)->reduce(false)->order(CouchbaseViewQuery::ORDER_DESCENDING);
$results = $bucket->query($query);

foreach($results['rows'] as $row) {
        var_dump($row['key']);
}
```

Here is the output from the above code:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "Australia"
  [1]=>
  string(15) "New South Wales"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "Sydney"
}
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "Australia"
  [1]=>
  string(15) "New South Wales"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "Sydney"
}
Reversing the order
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(13) "United States"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "Wyoming"
  [2]=>
  string(8) "Cheyenne"
}
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(13) "United States"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "Wyoming"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "Casper"
}
```